# How to make Toggle Selected Image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've tried several tutorials to create layouts like this, but they always fail.
maybe someone can help here

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please elaborate a bit more? As far as I know there is no direct way to make this. What you would need is to have a variable `selectedImageIndex` and you would have 2 "images" for each image, one that is highlighted and one that isn't and then you would write something like

```
child: selectedImageIndex == 1? HighlightedImage():NonHighLightedImage
```

and each image would be wrapped with a `Gesture Detector` so that when you tap it the `selectedImageIndex` changes. But again, that would mean that you have both versions of the image (or you have to manually somehow highlight it, or if it's an icon perhaps change color of icon. Please do provide more details

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int selected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.school),
              color: (selected != null && selected == 0)
                  ? Colors.blue
                  : Colors.grey,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  selected = 0;
                });
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.school),
              color: (selected != null && selected == 1)
                  ? Colors.blue
                  : Colors.grey,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  selected = 1;
                });
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for respond, yes if i clik image male then selected image male and change color,

Comment: I have added the new image

Comment: I added a code snippet of the general flow u want to follow using an icon instead of an image. for the image it could be the same but instead of doing this to the color you can do it for the whole image (you'd have 2 versions of each image, highlighted and not highlighted)

Comment: If you can give me a link both versions of an image(highlighted and not) i can show you the code for doing it with that

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Do let me know if it didn't work.

```
int _selectedA = 1, _selectedB = 1;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Center(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildCircleA(icon: Icons.bluetooth, selection: 1),
              _buildCircleA(icon: Icons.bluetooth_disabled, selection: 2),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildCircleB(icon: Icons.mail, selection: 1),
              _buildCircleB(icon: Icons.mail_outline, selection: 2),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _buildCircleA({IconData icon, int selection}) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => setState(() => _selectedA = selection),
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        border: Border.all(color: _selectedA == selection ? Colors.blue : Colors.transparent, width: 2),
      ),
      child: Icon(icon, size: 56, color: _selectedA == selection ? Colors.blue : null),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _buildCircleB({IconData icon, int selection}) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => setState(() => _selectedB = selection),
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        border: Border.all(color: _selectedB == selection ? Colors.blue : Colors.transparent, width: 2),
      ),
      child: Icon(icon, size: 56, color: _selectedB == selection ? Colors.blue : null),
    ),
  );
}
```